# Spiralling in Galaxy evolution

Tags: galaxy, supermassive-black-hole

Could some stars be orbiting galaxies in outward spirals instead of perfectly round circulation? Patterns of matter movement relate strongly to the galaxy centre.[image: Patterns of matter movement in galaxy associate to centre] A special relationship between the galaxy and the central object suggest the centre may be an origin point in 'outflow'. The BH central object behaves strangely by instigating the release outwardly of massive amounts of matter. This may form stars that spiral out across the galaxy. The grand design of features in galaxies may related to general outward spiralling.[image: X-ray emission from the monster galaxy and surrounding hot (30-70 million degrees C) cluster gas. The bright central source is the supermassive black hole at the core of Perseus A itself. Low density regions are seen as dark bubbles or voids, believed to be generated by cyclic outbursts of activity from the central black hole. Image credit: NASA/CXC/IoA/A.Fabian et al.]

Comment: This "outflow" is gas, not stars. The spiral pattern of disk galaxies has nothing to do with the outflow, but is density waves with enhanced star formation (and exists also in galaxies without an active nucleus).

Comment: Out-sprialling stars would need an energy input to "push" them out. There's no dynamics I know if that allows for such a thing.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, yes, it's possible.  Our moon is slowly moving away due to energy transfers from Earth related to tidal drag.  This is very slow spiral.

I do not know whether a star can experience sufficient tidal drag relative to the center of its galaxy to cause a change in orbit - and there are a few billion other objects in the galaxy producing gravitational force in other directions, making the analysis kind of messy.

Comment: Your analogy with the moon is not really relevant to stars orbiting in the galaxy at all.

Comment: @zephyr please quantify the failure

Comment: Quantify what failure?

Comment: Assuming particulate dark matter exists, then stars orbiting within a galaxy will experience dynamical friction, which will cause them to (*very, very* slowly) spiral *inwards*. This will take many times the age of the universe to have much of an effect, however.

Comment: The outward trajectory of stars is achieved from escaping the centre in this proposal. The outflow process from around the central object, powered by the SMBH, forms into stars in places like the Torus. That continues moving away from the centre. This would create a causality between that central object and the mass of the galaxy and a sedentary system of star forming (producing unified orbit and speed).